# How to prevent align environnement from stretching delimiters

Tags: align, alignment

Given

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    &x_4 &= 102/-24 = -51/12 \\
    &x_3 &= -48x_3 -24x_4 = -42 \\
    & &= -48x_3 -24\left(\frac{-51}{12}\right) = -42 \implies x_3 = 3\\
    &x_2 &= 36x_2 - 36x_3 + 36x_4 = -90
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

I am trying to find a way to have the equations aligned to the left as they would be normally in real life.  I don't understand why the delimiters get stretched out like that.

#### Things I have tried

- Aligned
- Alignat{2}
- searched internet
  but with no success

Comment: can you clarify your question? `align` has no effect on delimiters other than it selecting display math, they stretch to surround the fraction as you used `\left..\right`

Comment: it would be normal to align such a display on the `=` but you have specified non standard alignment, especially in row 3, but this is to do with the placement of `&` not the delimiters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't clear what output you expect, and the horizontal alignment just relates to the position of the `&` alignment markers and the delimiters around the fraction have no real effect here.

I would align on = using `alignat` for such a display.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    x_4 &= 102/-24 &&= -51/12 \\
    x_3 &= -48x_3 -24x_4 &&= -42 \\
        &= -48x_3 -24\left(\frac{-51}{12}\right)&& = -42 \implies x_3 = 3\\
    x_2 &= 36x_2 - 36x_3 + 36x_4 &&= -90
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```